# Is my cardio session good for losing body fat?

Tags: workout-routines, cardio

So I'm doing a cardio session once a week, about 60 minutes, that looks like this:

- 20 min cycling
- 20min Running (outside or on the treadmill)
- 20min Cross trainer

Does this session help me in losing body fat? Or should i focus more on doing one of those things but for a longer time? I also heard about High Interval training, how about this?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you lose body fat although this is highly dependent on your diet. 
If you are keeping your heart rate elevated and not leaving large gaps between each 20 minute session then you should drop body fat. You'll need to strategically reduce the amount of carbs you consume and cut out the foods with bad fats in them. 1 x 60 min session a week may not be enough for this. Again though this is highly dependent on your diet

Here is a great article to read with tips for losing body fat:

http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/drobson175.htm

Comment: Why reduce carbs?  Wouldn't it make more sense to reduce **calories**?

Comment: Well yes you could do that, but from the sounds of it our poster isn't very active with only one sixty minute session a week. Perhaps I am wrong in assuming this but I am going with what the information that the user has posted to us. Carbs when eaten in excess or at the wrong time of the day will definitely add to your body fat. This is why the word "strategically" was used in my previous post. I am not saying cut them out I am saying reduce them if your lifestyle is sedentary.

Comment: Weight loss is completely independent of macro-nutrient ratios. It only depends on consuming fewer calories than calories expended throughout the day (TDEE). Fat loss is more dependent on maintaining a smaller calorie deficit (10%-20% under TDEE) than macro ratios. In the end it doesn't matter if you follow a vegan diet (and thus have relatively high carbs), a ketogenic diet (hardly any carbs), or a balanced diet, as long as you eat below your TDEE you'll lose fat.

Comment: @rrirower It would make the most sense to reduce the amount of energy intake. Which is called calories by senseless people, because it should be called kilocalories. ;-)

Comment: @klaar: 1 food calorie *is* a kilocalorie. Both ways of saying it are equally correct.

Comment: @AlexL One calorie is one calorie, regardless of where it comes from. The fact that *some people* decided they didn't need the kilo-prefix doesn't make it correct. I know it's not right to quote wikipedia, but [here is it anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie#Nutrition). It's always kilocalories, that's why it's labeled 'kcal' on the nutrition table on the product's label.

Comment: @klaar: It's a matter of semantics (thus a matter of opinion). One calorie is indeed one calorie. One *food calorie* is effectively equivalent to 1 kcal in the *context* of food (which is why they're typically capitalized - to distinguish from standard calories). Also, not all nutrition labels use 'kcal' (most of the ones I've *ever* seen are simply in terms of Calories or kJ).

Comment: @AlexL Well no, it's not a matter of opinion, it's a matter of accepting unofficial units for property for which an official unit already exists. I also want to add that the 'food calorie' (== Calorie with a capital C) is never seen in my country. The nutrition tables always only specify the energy content using the units kJ and kcal, with their proportion being 4,2 (and not 4.200 like in food calorie, which is wrong btw). You also see that I use a comma as a decimal separator and a point as a thousand separator; that is also normal use in my country. Don't think it's all the same everywhere.

Comment: @klaar: You're starting to sound a little ethnocentric. I never said it was the same everywhere (just what *I've personally seen*). Just because you don't like one system of measurements, doesn't make them wrong. I assume you measure volume in liters. I measure it in gallons, so I must be wrong, right? Just nitpicking, but it's actually 4,18 Joule per calorie.

Comment: @klaar: To make my point a little differently, let's consider acceleration (second derivative of position). The official way of stating its units is m/(s^2). However, I can also state the units for acceleration as N/m (Newtons per meter). This doesn't "align" with the official way of interpreting acceleration, but that doesn't make it any less "right".

Comment: @AlexL I agree that one unit does not trump all others, but I tend to dislike the US with their waywardness towards the metric system, because from an outsider it seems completely absurd to *not* use the metric system and all of its compatibilities and simple ratios between units. As for acceleration, you'll find that the alternative unit is not N/m but N/kg, since F = m * a ([N] = [kg] * [m/s²]). My point, however, was that the Calorie is not just another unit, but a unit with the same name as another unit with a different value. *That* is thoroughly confusing and I dislike confusion.

Comment: @klaar: That's what I get when I respond right before taking a much needed nap. I do agree that the US' imperial system can be confusing (we did try converting to metric here, but it didn't work very well). I personally prefer units in S.I., but everyday convenience prevents me from actually converting to it. To be fair though, it's not the only thing that shares the same name but differs in value (epsilon_0 in electrostatics for example). I think we both agree on this, just were approaching it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having one session once a week try 30 min sessions 3 times a week. It will help you more than 1 session per week. During off days try to be active (walk, cruise around, do not use elevator etc) for at least 30 minutes. On diet part watch you total caloric intake especially from carbs as Caolan mentioned that we all mostly prone to consume.